# Indy 10 TIdSMTP Messaging in BCB 6

Tags: c++builder, indy10, c++builder-6

In an application developed with Borland C++Builder 6, I am using `TIdSMTP` and `TIdMessage` to send email messages. Due to problems for external applications with the usual mail server in the configuration, I am defining the connection data through my Gmail account as follows:

```
Correo->From->Address           = "******@******.org";
Correo->ReplyTo->EMailAddresses = "******@******.org";
Correo->From->Name              = "*******";
Correo->Organization            = "*******";

Enviar->Host     = "smtp.gmail.com";
Enviar->Password = "******";
Enviar->Port     = 465;
Enviar->Username = "******@gmail.com";
Enviar->UseTLS   = utUseImplicitTLS;

SSLIOHandler->Port               = 465;
SSLIOHandler->Host               = "smtp.gmail.com";
SSLIOHandler->Destination        = "smtp.gmail.com:" + IntToStr(SSLIOHandler->Port);
SSLIOHandler->SSLOptions->Method = sslvTLSv1_2;
SSLIOHandler->SSLOptions->Mode   = sslmUnassigned;
```

The emails are sent without any problem, but I am checking that in addition to the copies that I send one to my Gmail address. I have verified that the Gmail address appears in the message headers in the `Return-Path` field.

I have been looking and, at least in Indy 10 for BCB 6, I have not found how to modify that field. How can I get copies to only reach the address indicated in the `ReplyTo` field of `TIdMessage`?

Comment: On a side note, you DO NOT need to set the IOHandler's `Host`, `Port`, or `Destination` properties at all. Those are handled by `Connect()` for you. Also, you should be using `SSLOptions->SSLVersions` instead of `SSLOptions->Method`, and `SSLOptions->Mode` should be `sslmClient` instead of `sslmUnassigned`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TIdMessage.ReplyTo` property has no effect on the `Return-Path` header.  The `ReplyTo` is only used for the `Reply-To` header, which recipients use to reply back to the sender.  The `Reply-To` header is not used by the receiving SMTP server at all.

The `Return-Path` header is generated by the receiving SMTP server using the address specified in the sending client's SMTP `MAIL FROM` command. You can specify that address in the `TIdMessage.Sender` and `TIdMessage.From` properties (in that order), or by using one of the other overloaded `TIdSMTP.Send()` methods that has an `AFrom` parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and sorry for the delay in my reply. Indeed, the mail server data no longer appears in the message headers, but I still receive a copy of the messages at the Gmail address. It is not important but I wish it were not so.

Comment: @AngelMatillaCandás Gmail's SMTP server saves a copy of sent emails in your Gmail account's Sent folder, is that what you are referring to?

Comment: When I send emails from the external application using the Gmail server in addition to a copy to the replying address (******@internautas.org, different from the recipient) I also receive a copy to my Gmail address; maybe I'm looking at what's in the sent folder.

Comment: @AngelMatillaCandás if you don't put your Gmail address as a recipient in the email itself, then obviously the email can't be *sent* to your Gmail inbox. But since you are using GMail to send the email, GMail can certainly save a copy of whatever it sends. You need to configure your GMail settings to behave how you want in that regard.